# What is the parameter update rule for neural networks

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, computer-science, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently taking a machine learning course and had a question about the update rule for $\theta$ in neural networks. In the discussion of previous learning algorithms, the professor defined:
$$\theta := \theta - \alpha \frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$$

In the discussion of ANN classifiers, however, there was never an explicitly defined update rule, which I took to mean that it was the same as previous algorithms. If someone could verify that this is the case, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: what you posted is indeed a common updating updating rule in the context of training neural networks, but i have no way of knowing what your professor meant to do

Comment: As long as this is common for neural networks, then I am sure this is what was implied. Thanks for the verification.